# android bitmap getPixels return 0 at zero alpha Pixels

Tags: android, bitmap, pixel

first, i set all the pixels with zero alpha channel.

```
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);  
Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
// draw somethings in the bitmap...

bitmap.getPixels(pixs, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
for(int i=0;i<pixs.length;i++) {
    pixs[i] = pixs[i] & (0x00ffffff);
}
```

next i put these pixels into the bitmap and then call getPixels again.

```
bitmap.setPixels(pixs, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
bitmap.getPixels(pixs, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
```

the final result `pixs` is filled with 0.

why? why the bitmap lose rgb value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i find some weird in android/graphics/Bitmap.cpp, when the bitmap is `premultiplied`, it will use `FromColor_D32` to fill pixels into the bitmap which will do pre-multiplication for all pixels first. so `FromColor_D32_Raw` is what i want.

```
static FromColorProc ChooseFromColorProc(const SkBitmap& bitmap) {
    switch (bitmap.colorType()) {
        case kN32_SkColorType:
            return bitmap.alphaType() == kPremul_SkAlphaType ? FromColor_D32 : FromColor_D32_Raw;
        case kARGB_4444_SkColorType:
            return bitmap.alphaType() == kPremul_SkAlphaType ? FromColor_D4444 :
                    FromColor_D4444_Raw;
        case kRGB_565_SkColorType:
            return FromColor_D565;
        case kAlpha_8_SkColorType:
            return FromColor_DA8;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

the solution is adding the following before calling setPixels.

```
bitmap.setPremultiplied(false);
```

but it will also make the bitmap cannot be drawn by canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you initialize a bitmap, all pixels are initialized to 0.  0 & anything = 0.

If you want to set a default color, that's a horribly inefficient way anyway.  Set a canvas to draw to that bitmap and use drawColor